# Solving easy inhomogeneous second order recurrence equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know the method of solving the characteristic equation to solve homogeneous second order recurrence equations.

Now there is added an inhomogeneous term $c$, a constant.

I have seen many different approaches to handle such summands, but mainly when $c=2^n$ or something like this.

So is there an easy way to solve

$T(n+1)+aT(n)+bT(n-1) +c=0$, where $a,b,c$ are constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a linear recurrence equation, perhaps another way might be to use the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform first and then solve for $T(z)$ and use inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform to get $T(n)$. The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the recurrence equation you wrote above is
$$\mathcal{Z}\left[T(n+1)+aT(n)+bT(n-1)+c\right]=0\\zT(z)-zT(0)+aT(z)+bz^{-1}T(z)+c\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}=0\\T(z)=\frac{\left(T(0)z-T(0)+c\right)z^2}{(z-1)(z^2+az+b)}$$
which can be rewritten using partial fractions as
$$T(z)=a_1\frac{z}{z-1}+a_2\frac{z}{z+\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}+a_3\frac{z}{z+\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}$$
where $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ are
$$a_1=\frac{c}{a+b+1},\quad a_2=\frac{\left(-T(0)\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}-T(0)+c\right)\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\right)^2}{\left(-\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}-1\right)\left(-\sqrt{a^2-4b}\right)},\quad a_3=\frac{\left(T(0)\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}-T(0)+c\right)\left(\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{a^2-4b}\right)}$$
which can be transformed back to $n$-domain using $\mathcal{Z}$-transform as 
$$T(n)=a_1+a_2\left(\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\right)^n+a_3\left(\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\right)^n.$$
Here, I assumed that $a^2-4b\geq0$ to obtain real roots of the term, $z^2+az+b$ in the denominator of $T(z)$. If $a^2-4b<0$, then you have complex conjugate roots and the situation is a bit more involved however it is still solvable. See these notes http://staff.neu.edu.tr/~fahri/signals_10.pdf for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take your recurrence relation for $T(n+2)$ and subtract from it the recurrence relation for $T(n+1)$.

You obtain a higher order recurrence relation, but now it is homogenuous.

**Edit**

Completely forgot about this useful trick: if $d=1+a+b\ne 0$, then the sequence $T'(n):=T(n)+\frac cd $ satisfies the relation

$$T'(n+1)+aT'(n)+bT'(n-1)=0.$$
In other words, if $1$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial.

**Edit 2**
The case $1+a+b=0$ is more difficult. If $a=-1$, then the recurrence relation becomes quite trivial. If $a\ne 1$, then we can fall back to a standard method: let 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}-a&a+1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad u(n+1) =\begin{pmatrix}T(n+1)\\T(n)\end{pmatrix} ,\quad C= \begin{pmatrix}c\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the relation becomes
$$u(n+1)=Au(n)+C,$$ which is easy to solve:

$$u(n) =A^n D+\sum_{k=0}^n A^{n-k}C, $$ where $D$ is a constant vector found from initial data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have indeed seen this approach. But as third order recurrence equations are much nastier to solve than second order, I hoped for another solution that does not need to lift the order.

Comment: @user136457 see edit, I remembered another trick.

Comment: Thank you for the other trick. Seems to be quite useful for lot of problems. But I also have to solve some problems where $1+a+b=0$.

Comment: @user136457 see another edit.

Comment: Thank you for your second edit. I am not sure: do you mean when $a \neq -1$ there instead of $a \neq 1$? Moreover, why is the recurrence trivial when $a=-1$, so we only have
$T(n+1) - T(n) + b T(n-1) + c = 0$. Why is this easier to solve than other recurrences?

Comment: @user136457 in the second edit I suppose everywhere that $1+a+b=0$, so the condition $a=-1$ transforms the relation into $T(n+1)=T(n)-c$ (i.e. it becomes of the first order).